# Can I change the order of my weapons in Bioshock 2?

Tags: bioshock-2

Every time I take a picture of an enemy it takes a few changes to get to a good weapon.

Can I change the order if weapons on the PS3/360 version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the order of the weapons, but if you hold the right bumper you'll see a radial menu of all of your weapons.  Just tilt your left stick towards the one you want to select it immediately.

The left bumper will also bring up a plasmid radial.

Unfortunately, you can't rearrange the weapons/plasmids in the radial either.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start the camera it will automatically switch to whichever weapon was selected directly before you chose the camera, i.e. select the shotgun, select the camera, once you trigger the camera the shotgun will be selected automatically.